# Is it possible to use canonical tag in Blogger posts?

Tags: canonical-url, blogger, google-cache

I found one of my blog post was cached by Google (`www.example.com/post.html`). I found that comment page of the post was also cached (`www.example.com/post.html?showComment=1372054729698`).

These two pages are showing in Google SERP when I checked cached posts of my blog. Is it possible to use canonical tag on the post `www.example.com/post.html?showComment=1372054729698` so that Google won't penalize my original post? Is there any other ways to redirect a blog post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add canonical tags by editing your blog HTML template. (See this Google support article on how to edit the template HTML: https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46870?hl=en)

Then add code like this to the `<head>` of the document:

```
<ItemPage><Blogger><link href="<$BlogItemPermalinkURL$>" rel="canonical"/></Blogger></ItemPage>
<MainPage><link href="http://www.example.com/" rel="canonical"/></MainPage>
```

This uses Bloggers conditional tags (https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42059?hl=en) so that posts get their permalink as the canonical address (top line) and your blog homepage gets the root URL (bottom line).

Comment: Since this is an old answer and this thread still pop-ups on the top of the searches I am going to add that newer template uses this : 

`<link expr:href='data:blog.canonicalUrl' rel='canonical'/>`

Anyways, it is added already.